# Resizable popup window for Kendo MultiSelect and ComboBox

Tags: kendo-ui

Is it possible to make the popup window of the Kendo MultiSelect and ComoboBox widget resizable?

Answer (score 0):

By **default** kendo popup window is resizable true, so you can resize it using mouse pointer through the edge of window. You can also resize it using **setOptions** methods after the window already generated.

```
var theWindow = myWindow.data("kendoWindow").setOptions({
  width: "500px"
});
```

For more detail, I provide example to resize the window based on combobox and multiselect value. Please find code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamdesu/gk0tvkr1/).

As my example, using combobox you can resize width of the window and by using multi select you can resize **width** and **height** of the window. I call setOptions method inside onchange event of ComboBox and MultiSelect.